# I have done something wrong within my vim ~/.bash_profile file for set environment variable on MAC OS x

Tags: android, macos, vim, path

I set an env variable within my `.bash_Profile` file, but now when I the terminal I see.

[image: Terminal has launch like this]

I added android SDK and Platform tools path where and I'm not able to open `vim ~/.bash_profile` file:

[image]

Comment: Looks like your `.bash_profile` is mucked; I suggest posting the contents into your question.

Comment: Vim command not found? Don't have installed?

Comment: How to open .bash_profile? by which i can solve this issue.

Comment: You can use other editors. try `nano ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @ Sudo plz share details